# What was this NHL match, possibly in 1999, where the National Anthem was sung by Christina Aguilera?

Tags: history, nhl, match-identification

I'm trying to identify a game on which Christina Aguilera sang the National Anthem, as appears [on this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aDf-uxjIZj0).

I've got 3 leads:

1. The video title says it was on 1999.
2. In [another version](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2q2ul) of this video (whose title also says it's a 1999 game), the commentator says the game takes place in Anaheim.
3. We can see the blurry players' uniforms:

[image]

Can you identify this game, or at least identify some more clues that would help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fact finding of it taking place in Anaheim is correct based on announcers. I think it is safe to assume based on uniform colors that the team on the far side is the Ducks. They featured a light color top home jersey at that time.

Placing an identification on the opposing team is more difficult given video quality. Based on [this](https://www.hockey-reference.com/teams/MDA/2000_games.html) schedule, it would appear that there were 20 home games that took place in the year 1999 in the 99-00 season. This also could have been in latter half of the 1998-99  season, found [here](https://www.hockey-reference.com/teams/MDA/1999_games.html). That season featured 24 home games for the Ducks, with an additional 2 postseason games versus the Detroit Redwings. So a total of 46 NHL games were played there.

Based on the jersey colors, I believe the opposing team is the Philadelphia Flyers. The light strip across the neckline appears in only 2 jerseys that have a dark body and light number, Philadelphia and Tampa Bay. Tampa Bay, however, features a large white block on the bottom portion of the jersey which would be seen clearly even with poor video quality.

They only played @ Anaheim once in the year 1999 across the two seasons, which was [this](https://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/199911030MDA.html) game on November 3, 1999.

Aside from the jersey aspect, the "goalie matchup" comment at the end of your second video link would support this. The Anaheim goalie Dominic Roussel had posted the highest save percentage of his season in October, winning both games in which he appeared. Philadelphia's netminder John Vanbiesbrouck closed out 12th overall for the season and posted a .908 save percentage in the month of October. This would mean that the goaltender matchup would have been considered a meeting between two strong players at that point in the season, supporting this theory.

Therefore I believe this took place a the game between PHI and MDA on November 3, 1999.

Comment: In addition to the 24 home games duck played in the 1998-99 season in 1999, the Ducks also played 2 postseason games in April of 1999 at home

Comment: Edits shall reflect, thank you @alamoot

Comment: Thank you! There's another fact I didn't mention because it's obscure: Aguilera has an ad board behind her, with the letters "...ower ā de". I've tried to locate this ad board on videos circa that time, to no avail. However, Food4Less alongside Ralphs ads and Arrowhead's ad (0:01 and 1:21 on my first link, respectively) are visible in every video from that time (e.g [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=90&v=d_5VAoYFFcI&feature=emb_title), [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lDZTaCI1wUc&t=557s), [3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnFcBN2WWkE)).

Comment: @heyjude I did my best to find information about that company but had no luck in my search. Might have been a local company who is no longer is in business? Without increased video quality it really will be hard to determine a lot of other pieces.

Comment: @PaulWitry, the ad board is Powerade's old logo, with the "a" over a hockey puck, like [this one](https://nhl.bamcontent.com/images/photos/289652306/1284x722/cut.jpg).

Comment: @HeyJude would never have found that out, great work!